# jQuery chaining of the AJAX callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, callback

I have a centralized **ajaxSuccess** callback function that should initialize components returned by various AJAX calls around the project, something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (response, status, xhr) {
    initComponents();
});
```

So the module-level ajax call could just be like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "whatever",
   success: function(data) {
        // Do some stuff to update the DOM, like:
        $("container").html(data);
   }
});
```

without the need to perform the init of the eventual components I've in the returned HTML.

Now I've this issue: if the local ajax callback function is HUGE, I mean, if it performs a really heavy manulation of the DOM, it happens that the global ajaxSuccess function is fired BEFORE the elements returned by the call are placed in the DOM and available for jQuery.

That's because the callback functions are not chained, just exectuted in sequence (I think).

There is a way to be sure to perform the global ajaxSuccess after the local success callback function is completed?

Or, there is a better way to manage these behaviours?

**UPDATE:** 
Doing some logging I'm pretty sure the HTML is in place BEFORE we even entry on the global ajaxSuccess. 
The issue still remains, anyway, as specific jQuery selectors used in the initComponents() function is not retrieving the elements injected in the DOM.

If I perfom the initComponents() inside a setTimeout callback, it is working.... but I don't want to use a timeout...

It's like the updated DOM is not yet queryable when ajaxSuccess fires.

**UPDATE 2:**
False alarm. Actually the update of the html was inside a fadeOut callback function that was making it async in relation of other functions... My fault.

Comment: you should look at JavaScript's `Promises` which are an alternative to callbacks. They make life easier.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by chaining in this context. The only issue is which gets called first, the global `.ajaxSuccess()` function or the success function of the `$.ajax()` call. And it looks like the global function is called first.

Comment: Remember, Javascript is single-threaded, these functions won't run in parallel. So it doesn't matter how much work the local callback does. Once it gets started, nothing else runs.

Comment: @Barmar actually I'm pretty sure that the sequence of execution of the functions is correct (by logging), and you can see here : http://onegoodexample.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/sequences-of-jquery-ajax-event-handling/

Comment: As I said the sequence is correct, is just that the global ajaxSuccess is not WAITING the the local success completes the execution

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded. It has to wait, because they can't both run at once. You're not calling `alert()` in the local function, are you? That will allow the global function to run while you're responding to the popup.

Comment: There are no alerts at all. You're right, the sequence is logged correctly and the ajaxSuccess is not firing at the same time of the local success callback. I'm going to update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the global: true property to the $.ajax object.

Comment: It will bypass the global ajaxSuccess, which is not what I want